# Animate window width right to left

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I am making a sidebar-style app which is located on the left of right side of the screen.
I am trying to make it look like it's sliding in and out of the screen, but when it's on the right, it slides in from the left still.

I can't find any right to left options regarding window width, so I was hoping to find the answer here.

Here is my current working animation code for left to right:

```
    public static void AnimateSize(this Window target, double newWidth, EventHandler completed)
    {
        var length = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Settings.Default.AnimationTime);
        var sb = new Storyboard {Duration = new Duration(length)};

        var aniWidth = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        aniWidth.Duration = new Duration(length);

        aniWidth.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(target.ActualWidth,
            KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 00))));
        aniWidth.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(newWidth, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(length)));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(aniWidth, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(aniWidth, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty));

        sb.Children.Add(aniWidth);

        sb.Completed += completed;
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

called like this:

```
_window.AnimateSize(0, delegate { _window.Hide(); });
```

and this:

```
_window.Width = 0;
_window.Show();
_window.AnimateSize(Settings.Default.Width, delegate { });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        private void Animate(double beginfrom, double to, DependencyProperty dp)
        {
            var da = new DoubleAnimation {
                From = beginfrom,
                To = to,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)),
                AccelerationRatio = 0.1
            };
            var storyBoard = new Storyboard();
            storyBoard.Children.Add(da);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, this); //this = your control object
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(dp));
            storyBoard.Begin();
        }
```

Simple usage: `Animate(0, 250, WidthProperty);`

Comment: I have to resize it, or it will show up for users with multiple monitors.

Comment: You just have to change the dependency property.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar task to accomplish. I used to animate the left property of my window and make it appear as though it slides from the outside and disappears in the same fashion. but when a colleague who uses two screens used it , the window would slide onto the other screen.

The work around used was to simultaneously animate the width and left properties. this gives the effect of the window appearing at the desired location and unfurling towards the left.

```
DoubleAnimation daLeftAppear = new DoubleAnimation(popupWidthDetails.workAreaWidth, (<workAreaWidth> - <windowWidth> - 5), new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
        daLeftAppear.EasingFunction = new QuarticEase();
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(daLeftAppear, this.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daLeftAppear, new PropertyPath(LeftProperty));

        DoubleAnimation daWidthAppear = new DoubleAnimation(0, 100, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
        daWidthAppear.EasingFunction = new QuarticEase();
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(daWidthAppear, this.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daWidthAppear, new PropertyPath(WidthProperty));

        sbAppear = new Storyboard();
        sbAppear.Children.Add(daLeftAppear);
        sbAppear.Children.Add(daWidthAppear);
```